# Исключения в языке C

Tags: c, codeblocks

Пишу небольшую программу на C. Работаю в Code::Blocks. Искал, как можно обрабатывать исключения в языке C, нашёл описание __try __except на docs.microsoft.com, но компилятор почему-то на него ругается. Подскажите, как я могу сделать обработку исключений.

Comment: В стандартном языке C нет исключений.

Comment: Это чисто MS фишка.

Comment: `#include<setjmp.h>` ; `try , catch` == `setjmp` ; `throw` == `longjmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В плюсах исключения вызывают деструкторы всех переменных в стеке и возвращаются к области, где это исключение ловится.

В Си деструкторов нет и нет механизма фиксирования и выполнения критических участков, вроде освобождения мютексов, освобождение временной памяти и т.д. Всё остаётся на совести программиста и в его руках.

Возвращение в нужный участок программы и продолжение выполнения в месте, где находится точка фиксация реализована с помощью функции `setjmp`. Она ловит исключение или фиксирует начальную точку.

Запуск исключения производиться с помощью функции `longjmp`.

Она может создать только исключение типа `int` и если программист хочет работать с другим типом, то опять он должен всё это написать сам. Например исключение номер 3 будет означать, что само исключение хранится в структуре номер три.

Вот пример плюсовой, и аналог в Си:

**C++**

```
// g++ -std=c++11 mainpp.cpp -o mainpp
# include <iostream>

void fun(void) {
  std::cout << u8"fun:начало..."<<std::endl;
  throw 666 ; }
  
int main  ( ) {
  try {
    fun ( ) ; }
  catch(int e) {
    std::cerr<<u8"Ошибка номер "<<e<<std::endl;
    return e ; }
  catch ( ... ) {
    throw ; } }
```

**C**

```
// gcc -std=c11 main.c -o main
# include <stdio.h>
# include <setjmp.h>

// у каждой нити исключения движутся своим
// путём, по-этому у них отдельные указатели
_Thread_local jmp_buf * gloval_jbp ;

void fun  ( void  ) {
  printf ( u8"fun:начало...\n"  ) ;
  longjmp ( * gloval_jbp , 666 ) ; }

int main  ( ) {
  jmp_buf jb  ;
  jmp_buf * const jbold = gloval_jbp  ;
  // начала области захвата исключений
  gloval_jbp  = & jb  ;
  int exc ;
  switch  ( ( exc = setjmp  ( jb  ) ) ) {
  case  0 :
    fun ( ) ;
    // конец области захвата исключений
    gloval_jbp  = jbold ;
    break ;
  case  666 :
    // конец области захвата исключений
    gloval_jbp  = jbold ;
    printf ( u8"main:поймали исключение №666\n"  ) ;
    return  666 ;
  default :
    // нераспознанный номер исключения
    // конец области захвата исключений
    gloval_jbp  = jbold ;
    // пускаем обработку исключения дальше
    // аналог throw ;
    longjmp ( * gloval_jbp , exc ) ; } }
```

Comment: первый абзац явно нужно переписать. Даже наш анонимный минусатор смог это осознать

Comment: По крайней мере в linux вместо `setjmp/longjmp` надо использовать [sigsetjmp/siglongjmp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html)

Comment: Я знаю, что идёт `goto` в скрытый участок , который вызывает деструкторы. что я пропустил? @KoVadim

Comment: в плюсах, деструктор, который бросил исключение, если не предпринять никаких действий дополнительных, приговаривает приложение к закрытию.

Comment: Это опять, всё выдумки плюсов. На Си опять самому нужно в **default** свитче кинуть `longjmp` выше. А там как дойдет до нулевого указателя, и будет крах. @KoVadim

Comment: не смог распасить это.

Comment: Если вы в ветке **default** : запустите `gloval_jbp  = jbold ; longjmp ( * gloval_jbp , exc ) ;` это приведёт к дальнейшему поднятию обработки исключения выше. *аналог `throw;`*  А так как в `gloval_jbp` становится в конце концов нулевому указателю будет ошибка памяти. @KoVadim

Comment: ок, подождем кого то ещё. А  то мне кажется, что я забыл русский язык